# run visual studio from terminal

Tags: bash, visual-studio, terminal

I use Bash terminal on Windows. And I confused how can I run the Visual Studio solution from terminal?
For example

1. open the terminal
2. `git clone https://github.com/somerepository.git`
3. `cd somerepository`
4. `*VISUAL-STUDIO* somerepository.sln`
   Just only.

What can I write instead of *VISUAL-STUDIO*

UPD.
I use "Git For Windows", its provides a BASH emulation.

Comment: Is this Bash running through WSL?  Mingw?  Cygwin?

Comment: I just instaalled Git For Windows its provides a BASH emulation.